# Recovering wordpress blog from 16.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, restore, wordpress

One of my servers running Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) failed to start due to some bad blocks in the hard disk. Some how I could copy the data. I was running a wordpress blog on this server. Now how can I restore my blog on a new server running Ubuntu 18.04 using the recovered data? Simply copying the folder didn't work...it shows the error message "Error establishing a database connection". I used MySQL as database.

Comment: "it shows some error message for invalid database connection. I used MySQL as database." So fix those? you probably need to set up mysql to accept the wordpress user.  It is custom to add commands and errors to the question so those can be fixed.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I have updated question as per your suggestion. I had copied the directory "mysql" from /var/lib/ in the old machine to the same location in the new machine. But I am not sure how to set up mysql to accept the wordpress user.